# Rails 4 to where.not and OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, where-clause

Trying to rewrite this clause:

```
where("authorized_at IS NOT NULL OR paid_at IS NOT NULL")
```

to that prettier one:

```
where.not(authorized_at: nil, paid_at: nil)
```

but that produces "authorized_at IS NOT NULL **AND** paid_at IS NOT NULL". Is there no way to rewrite it with where.not ?

Answer (score 0):

Best I could get was:

```
where.not("authorized_at IS NULL AND paid_at IS NULL")
```

Strange that the hash counterpart will not work the same...